# Why two very similar Hive Queries return different results(one of which is clearly wrong)?

Tags: sql, hive

So I have this weird case in which two very similar queries return different results. The first query is this:

```sql
select src.period_num period_num,
src.flag flag,
src.week_num week_num,
((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num) year_num,
count(distinct src.id) result_count
from src_table src
group by src.period_num,
src.flag,
src.week_num,
((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num)
```

The second query is this one:

```sql
select src.period_num period_num,
src.flag flag,
src.week_num week_num,
((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num) year_num,
count(distinct src.id) result_count
from src_table src
group by src.period_num,
src.flag,
src.week_num,
((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num)
```

As you can see the queries have only one difference - in the first one we use addition(+), in the second one we use bit-wise OR(|)
My issue is that for the first one we receive something like this for a result(I've left only the significant part):

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--+
| period_num  | flag    | week_num  | year_num  | result_count  |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--+
| 6           | true    | 21        | 201906    | 94            |
```

While the second one returns this:

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--+
| period_num  | flag    | week_num  | year_num  | result_count  |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--+
| 6           | true    | 21        | 201902    | 87            |
| 6           | false   | 21        | 201902    | 7             |
```

The second result count is the correct one, with the correct grouping by flag, but you can see that now the year_num is messing up. Anyway my main issue is is that I can't understand what exactly is going awry with the first query, because it doesn't seem like it has something cardinally bad with it.
Any ideas and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bitwise or is a completely different operation to an addition. As such, it will produce completely different results.

Consider the following two examples of binary "operations".

First addition (1 + 3 = 4):

```
  0001
+ 0011
  ----
= 0100
```

and a bitwise or (1 | 3 = 3):

```
  0001
+ 0011
  ----
= 0011
```

I hope this helps you with your question.

Oh, and remember that multiplying a number by 100 will introduce two trailing zeros in base 10 (decimal), but in binary, there still could be bits set at the least significant places.

For example, 201900 is `110001010010101100` in binary.

without more details, it is difficult to explain why src.flag should magically change from false to true simply by using a bitwise or instead of an addition. Is it possible that preparing your example, you accidentally changed something else?

As promised, I've run your sample data through Spark-SQL. I reduced your dataset to just those 94 records with year_num = 2019 and period_num = 6.

Here is the result of the run showing the same answer being produced for both queries. Following that is the entire sequence which you can try yourself if you have access to spark-shell. It is possible that there is a bug in hive, but I wouldn't start with that assumption.

```scala
scala> val sumDF=sql("""select src.period_num period_num,
     |   src.flag flag,                                                                                                                                                                                           
     |   src.week_num week_num,                                                                                                                                                                                   
     |   ((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num) year_num,                                                                                                                                                        
     |   count(distinct src.id) result_count                                                                                                                                                                      
     |   from src_table src                                                                                                                                                                                       
     |   group by src.period_num,                                                                                                                                                                                 
     |   src.flag,                                                                                                                                                                                                
     |   src.week_num,                                                                                                                                                                                            
     |   ((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num)                                                                                                                                                                  
     |   """)
sumDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [period_num: int, flag: boolean ... 3 more fields]

scala> sumDF.show
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+
|period_num| flag|week_num|year_num|result_count|
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+
|         6|false|      21|  201906|           7|
|         6| true|      21|  201906|          87|
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+

scala> val orDF=sql ("""select src.period_num period_num,
     |   src.flag flag,
     |   src.week_num week_num,
     |   ((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num) year_num,
     |   count(distinct src.id) result_count
     |   from src_table src
     |   group by src.period_num,
     |   src.flag,
     |   src.week_num,
     |   ((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num)
     |   """)
orDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [period_num: int, flag: boolean ... 3 more fields]

scala> orDF.show
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+
|period_num| flag|week_num|year_num|result_count|
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+
|         6| true|      21|  201902|          87|
|         6|false|      21|  201902|           7|
+----------+-----+--------+--------+------------+
```

Here is the full job:

```scala
var dataDF=spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("source_data_from_op_2019_06.csv")
dataDF.printSchema
dataDF.count                                                                                                                                                                                 
dataDF.show

dataDF.createOrReplaceTempView("src_table")


val sumDF=sql("""select src.period_num period_num,
  src.flag flag,
  src.week_num week_num,
  ((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num) year_num,
  count(distinct src.id) result_count
  from src_table src
  group by src.period_num,
  src.flag,
  src.week_num,
  ((src.year_num * 100) + src.period_num)
  """)

sumDF.show

val orDF=sql ("""select src.period_num period_num,
  src.flag flag,
  src.week_num week_num,
  ((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num) year_num,
  count(distinct src.id) result_count
  from src_table src
  group by src.period_num,
  src.flag,
  src.week_num,
  ((src.year_num * 100) | src.period_num)
  """)
orDF.show
```

Are you able to try this in Spark-shell?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My issue is with why exactly the grouping doesn't work the same way in both cases e.g. first query returns only one row, second one returns two rows. I do understand how bitwise operations differentiate from the simple addition, but I am not sure how exactly it differentiates in the grouping of results in the end, as the grouping should be by the flag in this case.

Comment: can you post your example (with data) on db-fiddle or similar? I will leave the answer for now as it addresses the "year is messed up" portion of your question. you might need to use mysql or postgres, alternatively post your dataset as csv somewhere and I can try it using sparkSQL

Comment: Here is a link to the sample csv https://drive.google.com/open?id=12UsvDg77fxUbD5Wc4fr-w9ZkzEZbWi0e
I am not sure if this issue can be recreated in something else than Hive to be fair, but feel free to try if you want.

Comment: I don't have the freedom to use something different than what Hive offers in itself. As can be seen there are some workaround in Hive itself, but the main thing that I want to understand is **why** this discrepancy happens at all, as there is no logical answer for me, but I want to know why this happens, not just sidestep it. Thanks again for the time you've taken to analyze the data with different tools.

Comment: You are welcome. As you have observed (and I have verified with what you have provided), there is no apparent reason why you are getting the results that you are getting. This obviously means that there is something else going on. It is possible that there is a bug in your Hive implementation, but again I wouldn't start with that. What happens if you change the true / false indicator to a Y/N or a 1/0 (and make it an integer data type)? I suggest you play with it a little bit, it might give you some additional insights.